# WebAPI + Angular4 using IdentityServer4 CORS error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a ASP.Net core 1.X application which is setup to use IdentityServer4 with OpenIdConnect for its Authorization.

when I run the service use the **browser** to go to `http://localhost:xxx/api/mycontroller/myresource` this correctly redirects me to the identity server for authorization and then **returns value**.

now when I add a **Angular4** files and launch it, it shows the pages as expected, but when the request is made to the `http://localhost:xxx/api/mycontroller/myresource` from the `angularjs` I get a **CORS error** on my browser console.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=system.health.check&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64886%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20roles%20hierarchy%20healthcheck&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636396863541493382.OTI5NmUxOTYtYzE4Mi00MTY3LTgwYTYtNjlhYzhkNDQxYTY3MTYxNzI2MDUtOWM1Yy00MGExLWE2NTEtNmZjZmRjZmNjMmYz&state=CfDJ8HLk2yX8N6hEj4-UtnTRPL4rvxklhhFhg_Yc-8iFJwSP06FoI_9lUwaFJacx2xU81KDenMUSbsVAjF5QowMT_xRL2Z9mWyxFRykvBASUGB3mHk0RjaSCJzjYXtAYTbkbDF0wLzwALBTcaJ2tgwOwuG_vLWr2dAeiLyyqTiSVZqFziwssoMM_a9PXNAobGPHwl125pMihgXZxoylghIa0N_oS_4sswGCAr_kzW7cc9EMHFmApJTy7Yv29wUB4Tp2ddorOBKxt2t4-YqunsqHViKtlx-xUo0jFcuh30ZY4LDz90wLlHDvGkk_xYCqfJFBMaveNQAG5crvoPIiOYQcVJzNQMAzvXM7Z326E7pzVFVa-. Redirect from 'http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=system.health.check&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64886%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20roles%20hierarchy%20healthcheck&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636396863541493382.OTI5NmUxOTYtYzE4Mi00MTY3LTgwYTYtNjlhYzhkNDQxYTY3MTYxNzI2MDUtOWM1Yy00MGExLWE2NTEtNmZjZmRjZmNjMmYz&state=CfDJ8HLk2yX8N6hEj4-UtnTRPL4rvxklhhFhg_Yc-8iFJwSP06FoI_9lUwaFJacx2xU81KDenMUSbsVAjF5QowMT_xRL2Z9mWyxFRykvBASUGB3mHk0RjaSCJzjYXtAYTbkbDF0wLzwALBTcaJ2tgwOwuG_vLWr2dAeiLyyqTiSVZqFziwssoMM_a9PXNAobGPHwl125pMihgXZxoylghIa0N_oS_4sswGCAr_kzW7cc9EMHFmApJTy7Yv29wUB4Tp2ddorOBKxt2t4-YqunsqHViKtlx-xUo0jFcuh30ZY4LDz90wLlHDvGkk_xYCqfJFBMaveNQAG5crvoPIiOYQcVJzNQMAzvXM7Z326E7pzVFVa-' to 'http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Flogin%3Fclient_id%3Dsystem.health.check%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A64886%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520roles%2520hierarchy%2520healthcheck%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636396863541493382.OTI5NmUxOTYtYzE4Mi00MTY3LTgwYTYtNjlhYzhkNDQxYTY3MTYxNzI2MDUtOWM1Yy00MGExLWE2NTEtNmZjZmRjZmNjMmYz%26state%3DCfDJ8HLk2yX8N6hEj4-UtnTRPL4rvxklhhFhg_Yc-8iFJwSP06FoI_9lUwaFJacx2xU81KDenMUSbsVAjF5QowMT_xRL2Z9mWyxFRykvBASUGB3mHk0RjaSCJzjYXtAYTbkbDF0wLzwALBTcaJ2tgwOwuG_vLWr2dAeiLyyqTiSVZqFziwssoMM_a9PXNAobGPHwl125pMihgXZxoylghIa0N_oS_4sswGCAr_kzW7cc9EMHFmApJTy7Yv29wUB4Tp2ddorOBKxt2t4-YqunsqHViKtlx-xUo0jFcuh30ZY4LDz90wLlHDvGkk_xYCqfJFBMaveNQAG5crvoPIiOYQcVJzNQMAzvXM7Z326E7pzVFVa-' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64886' is therefore not allowed access.`

However the logs on the IdentityServer4 shows 
[image]

BTW `http://localhost:5000` is my IdentityServer4 address and `http://localhost:64886` is the service serving the Angular files and hosting the WebAPI.

Any ideas what I may be missing here?

**UPDATE 1**

Not sure if this helps, but my `OpenIdConnectOption` is setup as below

```
"OpenIdConnectOptions": {
  "AuthenticationScheme": "oidc",
  "SignInScheme": "Cookies",
  "Authority": "http://localhost:5000",
  "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
  "ClientId": "system.health.check",
  "ClientSecret": "secret",
  "ResponseType": "code id_token",
  "GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint": true,
  "SaveTokens": true,
  "Scope": [ "roles", "hierarchy", "healthcheck" ]
},
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I put in the `[Authorize]` attribute on  my `HomeController` things work as expected as its redirecting me to the login page even before the Angular files are shown. So does it mean that I cannot have the WebAPI controller protected unless the MVC is first Authorized? Also why do I get a CORS error in this case.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and ended up using the [Authorize] on HomeController, but you can do it within Angular as well

if you want to authorize within the Angular application you have to switch the client Grant Type to "Implicit" and do the oidc with an javascript library. You also have to change the responseType from "code id_token" to only "id_token" because in an angular app you cannot open a private backchannel for the code.

OIDC Javascript client: 
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

Here is an article which explains your approach:
https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/

Comment: I think i understand why this would fail as when a api call is made, angular is initialized and already has a opinion on what the UI looks like, so if it redirected to a different screen, it may not be possible to come back. However why CORS I don't get.

Comment: I might be because a redirect within a Ajax/XHR Request. Have to tried allowing the origin in the client setup of identity server? http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/cors.html